# PHP Adding Values With The Same ID's

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here's another PHP one for you all!

I have two arrays coming from two tables that have the same columns name but different values. I have created a query that call on both tables to dump the data into arrays. The values I get are: -

```
Array {
    [0] {
        [id] => 23,
        [count] => 300
    },
    [1] {
        [id] => 43,
        [count] => 400
    }
}
```

and

```
Array {
    [0] {
        [id] => 43,
        [count] => 200
    },
    [1] {
        [id] => 78,
        [count] => 55
    }
}
```

What I want to do is this: -

```
Array {
    [0] {
        [id] => 23,
        [count] => 300
    },
    [1] {
        [id] => 43,
        [count] => 600 <---- Notice how this has been added together
    },
    [2] {
        [id] => 78,
        [count] => 55
    }
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: and what did you try so far?

Comment: Just the usual array_merge and array_push

Comment: great, add the code... this way it will be easier to tell you whats wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_merge might seem like a good option at first but is really not as it does not merge numeric keys but rather just appends them.

The easiest would be to write your own function for this merge.

Would look something like this:

```
function merge_array($first, $second)
{
    $result = array();
    append_array($result, $first);
    append_array($result, $second);

    return $result;
}

function append_array(&$result, $array)
{
    foreach($array as $entry){
        $index = get_element_index($result, $entry);
        if($index < 0){
            // Add as normal
            $result[] = $entry;
        }else{
            $result[$index]['count'] = $result[$index]['count'] + $entry['count'];
        }

    }
}

function get_element_index($array, $element)
{
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){
        if($entry['id'] == $element['id']){
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```